# How to create view for tweet and facebook share button in android?

Tags: android, facebook, twitter, twitter-fabric

I am trying to create an app that has facebook share(using facebook SDK) and twitter's tweet button(using Fabric). I know I could do it via intents, but I need to create buttons for this.

Facebook SDK provides a view to create the like button by using

```
<com.facebook.widget.LikeView 
............/>
```

But I couldn't find similar view to create facebook share button. Same thing is true for twitter. There are views for embedding tweets but no view for creating a simple tweet button. Is there a reason for this? Also to create my own tweet and share buttons, I don't seem to find official "f" and "twitter-bird" logo to use in the button. Do they provide this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About Twitter Fabric, if you want send twitter button, you must implement it on your own. It's not hard,
Just use your `TwitterApiClient` method update():

```
apiClient.getStatusesService().update(composeTweet.getText().toString(), 
                    null, null, null, null, null, null, null, callback);
```

Where's "`composeTweet.getText()"` is your `EditText` field, and "`callback`" is `Callback<Tweet> callback`. You can read more about it parameters from "dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/statuses/update".

If you want set Twitter-Style to your button, just add to button xml: `style="@style/tw__Button"`

Also, the documentation have an [example](https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/android/compose), how to add entire TweetCompose activity. It may cause some troubles to implement, but you can use another example from [here](https://twittercommunity.com/t/android-tweet-composer/32905/2).

If you have more questions, you can find more help and useful info at "twittercommunity.com/c/fabric", because Twitter staff are answering there.

Comment: Thanks, after searching a bit, I too figured out that I have to implement it on my own. I think facebook share button is the same. I am not sure why both twitter and facebook decided to make it hard for us.